# How can I display a table cell below other cells (of the same row) with the same width as the table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with three columns in HTML. I want to display the third cell of every row below the two previous cells of the same row, with the same width as the whole table. I used `display: block` on the cells and floated them to where they're supposed to be.

My problem is, that using percentages for the table cells's / table's width makes the third cell either too small or too large depending on the value. 
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0w6jeLj/3/) of what it looks like with added borders.

I also tried using `box-sizing: border-box` on the third cell which only made it smaller.

Edit: What I'm trying to do is to make the table adjustable for different browser / device sizes. Keeping the table rows intact makes it easier for the bigger sizes. My only problem is that I can't get the third cell to conform to the table width in the smaller sizes.

Mockup:

```
small size:                   bigger size:
-----------------------       ----------------------------------
| Header 1 | Header 2 |       | Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 |
-----------------------       ----------------------------------
| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |       | Cell 1   | Cell 2   | Cell 3   |
-----------------------       ----------------------------------
| Cell 3              |
-----------------------
```

Comment: what do you want in your question explain clearly

Comment: Maybe you could provide some sort of visual mockup

Comment: Why do you want the third cell to be on the same row? Wouldn't the answer be to have that as a single cell on its own row?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, E-MM.
Consider adding a minimalistic example in your question and not a link.

Comment: create two rows, first with two cell and second one will have one cell with colspan="2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries (`@media screen and ( max-width: 800px ) { your css classes here }`) in css to adjust the behavior of the table. E.g. i have copied the JSFiddle code that you shared and tweaked it to use a media query in css to make the table show the third cell in the next line when the width of the browser is less than or equal to 800px otherwise it will show all cells in single row. In both cases the width of the cells will be adjusted based on percentage. You can add multiple media queries in css to  handle other screen sizes for different behaviours.

Here is the tweaked code link: https://jsfiddle.net/y9hbLjxt/

Hope this helps.